# Can i run gta v on low settings with 30-40 fps?

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card

Can I run GTAv on low settings with 30-40 fps?

I am about to buy GTAV, but I really dont know if my computer can run it. I have tried several websites, but with no answer.

[image]

Comment: Did you try and see?

Comment: [Benchmarks](http://www.notebookcheck.net/GTA-V-Benchmarked.140881.0.html). With the GT 750M, they got around 73.3fps `1366x768 Normal/Off AF:4x`. You might be able to tweak the settings to increase the resolution but they didn't get great fps 1920x1080.

Answer (score 1):

from [these benchmarks](http://www.notebookcheck.net/GTA-V-Benchmarked.140881.0.html) I can see that on low with a resolution of 1024x768 using a GT 750m they got an average of 79.8fps, but this cannot truly accurately represent an expected value at 1920x1080.

On medium, at 1366x768 they got an average of 73.3fps, and on high, at 1920x1080, the average frame rate dropped drastically to 17. This will obviously go up when you tweak the actual settings back to low, but I would recommend you find someone who is willing to let you sign into their steam account temporarily, and test it out from there before spending the money.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you to go to the lowest settings in game, you can play even more than 50 to 60 fps but it will not look gta v beacuse graphics wil be too low

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).